# SQL - Filter calculated column with calculated column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out the most dosed patients in a database. The sum of the doses has to be calculated and then I have to dynamically list out the patients who have been dosed that much. The query has to be dynamic, and there can be more than 5 patients listed - For example, the 5 most doses are 7,6,5,4,3 doses, but 3 people have gotten 5 doses, so I'd have to list out 7 people in total (the patients getting 7,6,5,5,5,4,3 doses). I'm having issues because you cannot refer to a named column in a where clause and I have no idea how to fix this.

The query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
    info.NAME, SUM(therapy.DOSE) AS total
FROM 
    dbo.PATIENT_INFORMATION_TBL info
JOIN 
    dbo.PATIENT_THERAPY_TBL therapy ON info.HOSPITAL_NUMBER = therapy.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.FORMULARY_CLINICAL clinical ON clinical.ITEMID = therapy.ITEMID
WHERE 
    total IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 SUM(t.DOSE) AS 'DOSES'
              FROM dbo.PATIENT_INFORMATION_TBL i
              JOIN dbo.PATIENT_THERAPY_TBL t ON i.HOSPITAL_NUMBER = t.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
              LEFT JOIN dbo.FORMULARY_CLINICAL c ON c.ITEMID = t.ITEMID
              GROUP BY NAME
              ORDER BY 'DOSES' DESC) 
GROUP BY 
    info.NAME
ORDER BY 
    total DESC
```

The database looks like this:

[image]

The main question is: how can I use a where/having clause where I need to compare a calculated column to a list of dynamically calculated values?

I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server 2012. The `DISTINCT` in the subquery is needed so that only the top 5 dosages appear (e.g. **without** `DISTINCT` I get `7,6,5,4,3` **with** `DISTINCT` I get `7,6,6,5,4` and my goal is the first one).

Comment: What's yoir DBMS? Does it support `DENSE_RANK`?

Comment: tag your DBMS please. as for your question, I guess this part is the issue `SELECT DISTINCT` so `DISTINCT` needs to be removed in order to list all doses then, in the main SELECT you can use `DISTINCT` this way will include patients who have 5 doses part.

Comment: I think you might've misunderstood the question. The inner query with the DISTINCT just returns the top 5 highest total doses from the whole db. I need to find all of the patients who got the top 5 highest total doses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most DBMSes support Standard SQL *Analytical Functions* like `DENSE_RANK`:

```
with cte as 
 (
    SELECT info.NAME, SUM(therapy.DOSE) as total,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(therapy.DOSE) DESC) AS dr
    FROM dbo.PATIENT_INFORMATION_TBL info
    JOIN dbo.PATIENT_THERAPY_TBL therapy ON info.HOSPITAL_NUMBER=therapy.HOSPITAL_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN dbo.FORMULARY_CLINICAL clinical ON clinical.ITEMID=therapy.ITEMID
    GROUP BY info.NAME
 ) 
select * 
from cte
where dr <= 5  -- only the five highest doses
ORDER BY total desc
```

Btw, you probably don't need the LEFT JOIN as you're not selecting any column from `dbo.FORMULARY_CLINICAL`